# Is a reason to believe something can be explained, also a reason to think that the explanadum exists?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness, mind-body

Is a reason to believe something can be explained, also a reason to think that the explanadum exists?

So, suppose someone agrees that our mental lives can be explained by brains and bodies, because they are very complicated structures. Would they be obliged to infer that complexity is a good reason to believe something is conscious?

Comment: seems a little like an ad absurdum of naturalism, if so... as, if i were to build something very complicated, and allow you to know nothing else about it, you'd be obliged to infer that it is conscious. and there may even be no other means to determine if it is -- for now!

Comment: If it's a true reason then yes. Complexity, if truly a reason for consciousness, may yet be a necessary but insufficient condition for consciousness. One reason among others.

Comment: A good question that needs way more specificity. In its article Explanandum and explanans, Wikipedia uses the examples "smoke" and "fire". How much more firmly can you tie this question down?